# iOS Autolayout: constraints for three squares

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to achieve a very simple scenario using auto layout but without success. Please help me...
I need 3 squares with a dynamic size(ex: on iPad, all of them should be scaled) on a table cell.

I have spend already some hours finding a solution....
This picture showing how the view should look like:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Just "a dynamic size"?  If you don't tell us what size you want them to be how are we supposed to tell you how to tell autolayout?

Comment: Hmm...I don't have a specific size, but let's have this one: height for 4 inch - 100, height for 12.9 inch - 200. The hight for table view cell is 300 on iPhone's, and 600 on iPad's

Comment: @hackmajoris what about width?

Comment: How about a picture?

Comment: The width isn’t necessary because of Aspect Ratio constraint. It should be the same as height, because of square.

Comment: Using a picture - isn’t a solution,  because I have to use a custom view which represents a circle and it should be a square, in order to have a perfect circle.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with autoresizing tool which is appear in size inspector.

Step1: **Place your views in which ever pattern you want.**

Step2: **Then select a view and click on size inspector.**

Step3: **Click to select inner arrows of autoresizing tools rectangle and deselect outer arrows (predefined selections).**

Step4: Repeat same step for the remaining squares. Thats it. Verify below image which i have done.
[image]

Do same for by placing table view in your storyboard, verify below image for which points autoresizing settings for table view clearly.
[image]

Comment: It seemed to be perfect...but on iPad's, the view's is't really a square.

Comment: Yeah slightly it varies but this is the only solution i believe for your requirement.